# Tensorflow RNN Input shape

Tags: tensorflow, recurrent-neural-network

**Updated question:** This is a good resource: http://machinelearningmastery.com/understanding-stateful-lstm-recurrent-neural-networks-python-keras/

See the section on "LSTM State Within A Batch".

If I interpret this correctly, the author did not need to reshape the data as x,y,z  (as he did in the preceding example); he just increased the batch size. So an LSTM cells hidden state (the one that gets passed from one time step to the next) started at row 0, and keeps getting updated until all rows in the batch have finished? is that right?

If that is correct then why does one ever need to have a time step greater than 1? Could I not just stack all my time-series rows in order, and feed them as a single batch?

**Original question:**
I'm getting myself into an absolute muddle trying to understand the correct way to shape my data for tensorflow, particularly around time_steps. Reading around has only confused me further, so I thought I'd cave in and ask.

I'm trying to model time series data in which the data at time t is a 5 columns in width (5 features , 1 label).

So then t-1 will also have another 5 features, and 1 label
Here is an example with 2 rows. 
x=[1,1,1,1,1] y=[5]
x=[2,2,2,2,2]  y=[15]

I've got an RNN model to work by feeding in a 1x1x5 matrix into my x variable. Which implies my 'time step' has a dimension of 1. However as with the above example, the second line I feed in is correlated to the first (15 = 5 +(2+2+2+2+20 in case you haven't spotted it)

So is the way I'm currently entering it correct? How does the time stamp dimension work?

Or should I be thinking of it as batch size, rows, cols in my head?

Either way can someone tell me what are the dimensions are I should be reshaping my input data to? For sake of argument assume I've split the data into batches of 1000. So within those 1000 rows I want a prediction for every row, but the RNN should be look to the row above it in my batch to figure out the answer.

x1=[1,1,1,1,1] y=[5]
x2=[2,2,2,2,2]  y=[15]
...
etc.

Comment: I am not mistaken each row corresponds to one time-step. If so, then your input tensor should have the shape of (1000, number of rows, 5) assuming you are using `dynamic_rnn` with `time_major = False`. Do you want to predict `y` at time-step (i.e., row) `t+1` by looking at `x` at `t`?

Comment: The way I think of it is that each row is a time step, but I want a prediction for each row, utilizing that row and the row that came  before it using the power of an LSTM. Will add more info / clarification to my question right now...